# New Android 9 'phone - where is "schedule power off / on"?

Tags: 9.0-pie, power-on

I always use this feature to save battery, but can't find it on my new Android 9 'phone.

Where has it gone?

---

[Update] the 'phone is a Ulefone Armor X3. For the least 5 or 6 years, I have had exclusively Ulefone and they all had this feature, so I just assumed that it was baked in to Android itself. Otoh, they were all other models & pre Android 9.

Comment: Which device are you using? I don't think scheduled start/shutdown is a universal feature in Android. Might be OEM specific, such as Xiaomi, OnePlus, etc.

Comment: Thanks. Its a Ulefone Armor X3, All previous Ulefone  for the last 5 or 6 years had this feature. They also had Android version < 9. See [App to schedule Android power off / on at specified times?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/77672/app-to-scheduel-android-power-off-on-at-specififed-times)